# How to detect Window Location Change using Win32 API

Tags: c#, winapi, window

I have been developing an app. I want to check if window location is changed or not. I don't want to read always position of the window. Instead of it, I need a method which is triggered when the window is moved by user.

Is it possible to find it?

PS: The window is not on my program, its an external app and I use some API functions to control the window.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is best done using [WinEvents](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd373889.aspx). The [Event Constant](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd318066.aspx) to listen for is `EVENT_OBJECT_LOCATIONCHANGE`:

> An object has changed location, shape, or size. The system sends this event for the following user interface elements: caret and window objects.

Comment: `EVENT_OBJECT_LOCATIONCHANGE` doesn't work for command prompt (cmd.exe), it also doesn't fire `EVENT_OBJECT_DESTROY` like all other windows. Any suggestions?